What are “all the usual rights and remedies” according to the CCTS, notwithstanding Telecommunications Act 1993, s. 72(3)?

If you reject the Investigation Findings, your provider is not required to carry out any remedies. You would retain all the usual rights and remedies [emphasis mine], and you are free to pursue them.

But see Wilson v. Telus Communications Inc., 2019 FC 276 (CanLII), para 23.

[23]  Subsection 72(3) of the Telecommunications Act provides an exception, where the action is for “breach of a contract to provide telecommunications services.” This provision was specifically dealt with by the Court in B & W Entertainment Inc v Telus Communications Inc (2004), 134 ACWS (3d) 939 (Ont Sup Ct) at paragraphs 16-17, where the Court stated:



Section 72(3) of the Act confers upon the court the jurisdiction to hear claims for loss or damage by a person as a result of any act or omission that is contrary to the act, or to a decision or regulation made under the Act. However, under s. 72(3), there is no statutory right of action for loss or damage "in any action for breach of a contract to provide telecommunications services...
This is a clear expression by Parliament that disputes involving contracts to provide telecommunications services should be resolved by the CRTC and not by the courts.


Doesn’t this Telecommunications Act 1993, s. 72(3), forestall "all the usual rights and remedies", and gainsay the CCTS (Commission for Complaints for Telecom-television Services)?
If not, what does CCTS mean by "all the usual rights and remedies”, in the teeth of this s. 72(3)? What "rights and remedies" survive and overcome this s. 72(3)?
This question is publicly important! Too many self-represented litigants are unaware of this s. 72(3) that bars, and makes them lose, their lawsuits — see Dell v. Bell Mobility Inc., 2023 BCCRT 330 (CanLII), para 19.


Multiple CRT decisions have noted that the federal court has interpreted section 72(3) of the Telecommunications Act as saying that disputes involving telecommunications services contracts should be resolved by the CRTC and not the courts. These decisions also accordingly conclude that, although the CRT is not a court, the CRT does not have jurisdiction over claims about telecommunications services contracts. See, for example, Hafizi citing Wilson v. Telus Communications Inc., 2019 FC 276 at paragraph 17, Mekies v. Fido Solutions Inc., 2020 BCCRT 176, and Tang v. Rogers Communications Canada Inc., 2020 BCCRT 1408.



Probably related (possibly a duplicate??): Why didn't Telecommunications Act 1993, s. 72(3), bar David Ramsay's claim against Bell Canada?.

@TripleHound Not a duplicate! David Ramsay's small claim lies in restitution. Here, I am asking about ANY and ALL rights and remedies!

No problem. I don't know the subject matter, I just remembered seeing the earlier question about CRT decisions.

In my opinion, a court should not refrain from their general jurisdiction and should not apply res judicata with CCTS decisions, since those decisions ("investigative findings") become non-binding if the consumer rejects them. By allowing CCTS decisions to be rejected and without providing another binding process, the court should not give deference to CRTC when considering a claim not arising only under the Telecommunications Act after the CCTS process had been completed.

Section 72(3)

(3) Nothing in subsection (1) or (2) applies to any action for breach of a contract to provide telecommunications services or any action for damages in relation to a rate charged by a Canadian carrier.

only bars claims made under s. 72(1):

72 (1) Subject to any limitation of liability imposed in accordance with this or any other Act, a person who has sustained loss or damage as a result of any act or omission that is contrary to this Act or any special Act or a decision or regulation made under either of them may, in a court of competent jurisdiction, sue for and recover an amount equal to the loss or damage from any person who engaged in, directed, authorized, consented to or participated in the act or omission.

which provides a statutory cause of action for a civil claim under the Telecommunications Act, which, due to s. 72(3), was never part of the "usual" rights and remedies.
The wording of s. 72(3) should not apply to any other causes of action arising from other statutes or common law.

This is a clear expression by Parliament that disputes involving contracts to provide telecommunications services should be resolved by the CRTC and not by the courts.

I believe the sentence is too strong if taken to bar any contract claims in court (even those not resolved in a binding manner by CRTC), and the BCCRT decisions have taken a similarly too strong position. However, BCCRT's enabling legislation does allow it to defer to more specialized processes even if it has jurisdiction.
It would be hard to believe for me that a superior court of inherent jurisdiction would disclaim jurisdiction due to s. 72(3) after CCTS findings are rejected. A court may choose to defer jurisdiction by way of a temporary stay if it considers another forum more appropriate: in the B & W case where the above sentence came from, the court granted a stay pending CRTC determination. Note that the Federal Court is not a court of inherent jurisdiction, but a statutory court with limited jurisdiction under federal law.
There are some decisions that allude to the usual jurisdiction of courts, for example, Nelson v. Telus Communications Inc. (Part 2), 2021 ONSC 23 (CanLII)

Ms. Nelson would have a breach of contract claim for services paid for but not delivered, but she would not have a statutory cause of action under s. 72 (1). Subject to Telus’ jurisdictional arguments, discussed below, Ms. Nelson would simply advance an action in the Small Claims Court branch of the Ontario Superior Court and she would not need the statutory cause of action.
...
In any event, I conclude that Ms. Nelson does not have a claim under s. 72 (1) of the Telecommunications Act because her claim is in substance a breach of contract claim that s. 72 (3) of the Act precludes from being a statutory cause of action. Section 72 (3) does not preclude a common law breach of contract claim, but Ms. Nelson has not brought such a claim.

or, in Bell Canada c. Aka-Trudel, 2018 QCCA 829 (CanLII)

[30]        En somme, les appelantes ne convainquent pas que le litige découle de la Loi ou de toute autre réglementation fédérale. Il n’y a rien dans ce litige qui interpelle la compétence spécialisée du CRTC. Même en tenant pour acquis que le paragraphe 72(3) de la Loi attribue une compétence exclusive au CRTC, ce qu'il n’est pas nécessaire de trancher, le litige ne repose aucunement sur un manquement aux dispositions de la présente Loi ou d’une loi spéciale, soit à une décision ou un règlement pris au titre de celles-ci.


[30] In short, the appellants do not convince us that the dispute arises from the Act or any other federal regulation. There is nothing in this dispute that calls into question the CRTC's specialized jurisdiction. Even assuming that subsection 72(3) of the Act confers exclusive jurisdiction on the CRTC, which it is not necessary to decide, the dispute is in no way based on a failure to comply with the provisions of the present Act or a special statute, or with a decision or regulation made thereunder.

The Quebec case was based on a cause of action provided by Quebec law and has some particularities where CRTC had forborne/refrained from claiming jurisdiction.

thanks for this great answer! What authorities or law support your belief that "the sentence is too strong if taken to bar any contract claims in court (even those not resolved in a binding manner by CRTC), and the BCCRT decisions have taken a similarly too strong position"?

@Bes The courts in B&W, Nelson, Aka-Trudel suggest that the courts are not deprived of their inherent jurisdiction over common law civil claims, even if the court may decide to defer to CRTC by way of stay; you've also found the Ramsay case where the small claims accepted to exercise jurisdiction.

Even the decisions against the consumer (B&W, Nelson) accepted that if CRTC declines jurisdiction, the common law claims could then proceed in courts. I believe that CCTS findings rejected by the consumer has no legal value (14.2(c) of the CCTS Procedural Code) and should be considered as if the CRTC declines to act (if CRTC has no other procedure available). I am doubtful that CCTS is even an administrative tribunal. I don't think anyone has tested the claims explicitly though, other than in the Quebec cases (which is distinguishable due to how Quebec civil law is set up).

I think BCCRT was mistaken in taking the Federal Court's rejection of jurisdiction for itself. Federal Court's jurisdiction is very limited and requires an explicit conferral; BCCRT's jurisdiction under province's constitutional powers over civil rights and administration of justice should not be limited in the same way. I would hope that someone would eventually ask the BC provincial court to exercise jurisdiction if BCCRT refuses.

Thank you. I hope you can add these great comments into your already capital answer?
