Why did Marjorie Nelson's lawyers bring just two statutory causes of action, but no “common law breach of contract claim”?
Plaintiff, Marjorie Nelson, was represented by two lawyers Douglas Lennox and Careen Hannouche in Nelson v. Telus Communications Inc. (Part 2), 2021 ONSC 23 (CanLII), [27].

[27]  On January 5, 2018, Ms. Nelson commenced her proposed class action. She advanced two statutory causes of action; namely: (a) the statutory cause of action pursuant to s. 72 of the Telecommunications Act; and (b) the statutory cause of action pursuant to sections 16 and 17 of the Wireless Services Agreement Act, 2013.

Imagine that Plaintiff’s 2 lawyers were competent, and did consider "common law breach of contract claim” before they issued proceedings. Why might not they have advanced any “common law breach of contract claim” that was hinted to by Perell J. at [49]–[50] ?

[49]           Instead of relying on the statutory claim, had Ms. Nelson foregone the statutory claim, she could have done what the Representative Plaintiff did in Anderson v. Bell[13] which was to advance a breach of contract claim and then she could resist Telus’ reliance on the no-refund provision in the contract as illegal precisely because it was contrary to the Telecommunications Act. In Anderson, consumers in the North West Territories were charged for a 911 service that was not actually available. The action was certified as a breach of contract claim and the Representative Plaintiff was successful at the common issue trial, and the judgment was affirmed on appeal.
[50]           In any event, I conclude that Ms. Nelson does not have a claim under s. 72 (1) of the Telecommunications Act because her claim is in substance a breach of contract claim that s. 72 (3) of the Act precludes from being a statutory cause of action. Section 72 (3) does not preclude a common law breach of contract claim, but Ms. Nelson has not brought such a claim.


See also https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/105613/what-are-all-the-usual-rights-and-remedies-according-to-the-ccts-notwithstand
